# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag' (using eyed3)

Tags: python, metadata, eyed3

I want to create a list of dictionaries with the keys: Title, Album, and Artist.

I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag'

line 17:

```
song_title  = mediafile.tag.title,
```

Here is my code:

```
import glob
import eyed3

class Song:
    def __init__(self, song_title, album, artist_name,):
        self.song_title  = song_title
        self.album       = album
        self.artist_name = artist_name

songs = []

media = glob.glob('C:\\My Stuff\\My Music (For Groove)/**/*.mp3', recursive=True)

for song in media:
    mediafile = eyed3.load(song)
    a = Song(
            song_title  = mediafile.tag.title,
            album       = mediafile.tag.album,
            artist_name = mediafile.tag.artist, 
        )
    songs.append({'Title' : a.song_title, 'Album' : a.album, 'Artist' : a.artist_name})
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `mediafile = eyed3.load(song)` is returning `None`

Comment: please, how can I fix that?

Comment: You could add a check for song before calling `load()`. Maybe `if os.path.exists(song):`

Comment: Adding lots of `print` statements should help you see what is failing at what line.

Comment: okay, I'll try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From eyed3 [documentation](http://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/eyed3.html#eyed3.core.load):

> Loads the file identified by path and returns a concrete type of
>   eyed3.core.AudioFile. If path is not a file an IOError is raised. None
>   is returned when the file type (i.e. mime-type) is not recognized.

In your code, you are trying to extract the tags from the `mediafile` before you know it's not `None` and this is why you are getting this.

You could do a couple of things:

try/catch for `IOError` and check for `None` value of your `mediafile` if the file's content is not recognized:

```
try:
    mediafile = eyed3.load(song)
    if mediafile:
        ... extract tag
    else:
        ... log not recognized file format
except IOError:
    .... log Exception
```

Comment: I don't know if it's this library, or if things have changed in the past millennium or so, but I remember one of the main ID3 libraries would treat a perfectly valid MP3 file with APEv2 tags (or anything else that confuses it) as not being an MP3 file, and not let you add ID3 tags to it.

Comment: I have an mp3 file which loads fine, returned type is eyed3.mp3.Mp3AudioFile, yet the .tag attribute is NoneType.

Answer (score 2):

If you load a file that doesn't have a tag yet, you need to initialise it

```
f = eyed3.load(file)
if not f.tag:
    f.initTag()
```