Eyed3 album command not functioning correctly
I am trying to use eyed3 to get the album info of an mp3 I pull from a directory.  The code below has worked for the last two years but today when I tried to run the program it gave me this error.
album = song.tag.album
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'album'

I have changed nothing but it is not working anymore.  I checked the documentation and it has not changed and the code should still work.  Any help would be appreciated
 path = os.path.join(paths, file)
 song = eyed3.load(path)
 name = Path(path).stem
 album = song.tag.album
 alreadyexist = False

Normally gets album data fine, now gives me an error

MP3 files are not required to have ID3 tags at all; you have apparently finally run into a file that doesn't.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67283751/1709364, or simply check song.tag before trying to use it.

that seemed to work, thanks!
